# How recent are 'Deleted recent answers'?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, privileges

I was looking for my deleted answers till date, and found this link **[Deleted recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/3639582)**.

It had answers of *current month only*. I went through the Help section but did not find anything mentioned to view all of them.

How Recent are these answers?

And if the old ones are deleted, are they permanently deleted from the site, or they are visible to moderators?

Comment: Last 60 days; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/248731. And I understand that older questions aren't deleted from the database, so mods can still find them.

Comment: Is there no way users could access them? I could look for them in the `reputation` section but I dont think they were non-zero score answers.

Comment: Not unless you kept a bookmark to the link; they won't appear anywhere on your profile. Deleted questions also don't impact your reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll only see posts that were [*created* in the past 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492), and have since been deleted. From the original post detailing this:

> [...] we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently **limited to those posted in the past 60 days.**

*Emphasis mine*.

That means you will not find posts there that were created more than 60 days ago, regardless of when they were deleted.

There are no public lists of deleted posts outside of that view; you'd have to have a bookmark or other record of the post link (say, in a comment or another post, or the Internet Archive) if you wanted to locate those posts by other means.