# What could make my question disappear from SO?

Tags: support

I asked a question on Stack Overflow a couple of months ago, even offered a bounty on it. I'd bought a Chromebook for development and found I could not get Android Studio to run an emulator. I didn't get much response to the question, the bounty expired and it was downvoted once. I had not visited the site for a week or two until today and I cannot find any record of that question.

So, what could possibly have made this question disappear like that? Is it possible that someone else deleted it?

Comment: Either community deletion or the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Going to this question page directly could probably tell you, should you still have the link.

Comment: There's the roomba script.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289687/how-recent-are-deleted-recent-answers there is a similar link in your profile for questions. If you didn't ask it more then 60 days ago it should be available there.

Comment: I found a link to my question in "deleted recent questions" and it was deleted by "Community" - thanks for resolving this for me

Comment: Was the bounty refunded after the delete? Looks that way from your rep tab as there is no deduction for bounty.

Comment: If you can give a link to it here, 10K+ users can see it, and offer feedback on it if you like. I presume it is closed, and there is a reason box supplied?

Comment: Google searching turned up the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679992/unable-to-run-android-studio-emulator-on-chromebook

Comment: I think your issue may have been that it's not really a programing question or directly related to programing tools. You might have better luck on SuperUser.